# Google script pushing data from one tab to another while retaining data validation

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following google apps script. It functions to look in my PENDING-IP tab and check the status (column G). If the status is "Screened - Ready for Review," then it moves the entire row of data to the SCREENED - READY FOR REVIEW tab.

My problem is this - the data in columns L, M, and N of the PENDING tab is a checkbox, but when it pushes it to the SCREENED tab, it changes it to TRUE or FALSE. Is there a way to modify my script to push the data *with validation* to retain the checkboxes? Thank you!

```
function screened() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('PENDING-IP'); //source sheet
  var testrange = sheet.getRange('G:G'); //range to check
  var testvalue = (testrange.getValues());
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('SCREENED - READY FOR REVIEW'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var j =[];
  //Condition check in G:G; If true copy the same row to data array
  for (i=0; i<testvalue.length;i++) {
    if ( testvalue[i] == 'Screened - Ready for Review') {
      data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,25).getValues());
      //Copy matched ROW numbers to j
      j.push(i);
    }
  }
  //Copy data array to destination sheet
  csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
  //Delete matched rows in the source sheet
  for (i=0;i<j.length;i++){
    var k = j[i]+1;
    sheet.deleteRow(k);
    //Alter j to account for deleted rows
    if (!(i == j.length-1)) {
      j[i+1] = j[i+1]-i-1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This `if ( testvalue[i] == 'Screened - Ready for Review') {` should be `if ( testvalue[i][0] == 'Screened - Ready for Review') {` also I would use `sheet.getRange(1,7,sh.getLastRow(),1)` instead of `sheet.getRange('G:G')`  The latters often sticks a bunch of null at the bottom.

Comment: I would do this `data.push(sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,25).getValues()[0])` rather than this: `data.push.apply(data,sheet.getRange(i+1,1,1,25).getValues())`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

I haven't actually tested this except in a simpler situation

```
function screened() { 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('PENDING-IP'); 
  var testrange=sheet.getRange(1,7,sheet.getLastRow(),1); 
  var testvalue=testrange.getValues();
  var valids=testrange.getDataValidations();
  var csh = ss.getSheetByName('SCREENED - READY FOR REVIEW'); //destination sheet
  var data = [];
  var valid = [];
  var j =[];
  var d=0;
  for (var i=0;i<testvalue.length;i++) {
    if (testvalue[i][0] == 'Screened - Ready for Review') {
      data.push(sheet.getRange(i+1-d,1,1,25).getValues());//I am not sure but I could see having to put [0] at the end here
      valid.push(sheet.getRange(i+1-d,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getDataValidations());//I am not sure but I could see having to put [0] at the end here
      sheet.deleteRow(i+1-d++);//this should delete matching rows
    }
  }
  csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(data);
  csh.getRange(csh.getLastRow()+1,1,data.length,data[0].length).setValues(valid);

}
```

What I've found is that you can treat the validations the same way you treat the data by replacing getValues() with getDataValidations() and setValues() with setValidations();

Comment: Thank you, @Cooper. This script doesn't seem to be working for me, though. You included some extra periods (after data.push and valid.push), which I removed, and you have sh instead of csh, but once I fixed those errors, the script ran. It moved the data to the correct tab, but it still changed the data from checkboxes to TRUE FALSE.

Comment: Can you provide a sample spreadsheet?  And I don't mean an image of one.  I want an actual spreadsheet so I can copy the data and test with it.

Comment: It's not a public link

Comment: Still not a public link